# std unary functions for common operations

Tags: c++

Is there a reason to not have unary versions for the binary functions from [functional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional)?

I know is simple to create unary versions by using `std::bind`, but the code looks ugly:

```
std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::bind(std::less_equal<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 42));
```

I think it would be much nicer to have something like:

```
std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::less_equal<int>(42));
```

Comment: It's not so bad with lambdas.

Comment: @LogicStuff I still think is more readable with names than with lambdas

Comment: Supporting unary and binary function at same time might be confusing.

Comment: @Felics  In general I agree with you. However in this expression std::less_equal<int>( 42 ) there is not clear whether 42 is the left of the right operand of the comparison.

Comment: What if I want 42 to go on the left? Do we need 2 unary functions for each binary one? How do we call them?

Comment: Note that [std::binary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function) and [std::unary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) were deprecated in C++11 and will be removed in C++17.

Comment: @Felics you can name your lambdas `const auto some_name = []{};` and then just use the named object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow maybe the name is not the best, `less_equal_than` or `less_than` might be a better name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO since C++11/14, lambdas make this sort of predicates superfluous?

```
find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](auto x){ return x <= 42; });
```

Comment: I do not think so. Using a meaningfull name for a functional object  instead of a lambda makes the code more readable and clear because the name of the functional object is well-known.

Comment: I kind of agree with @VladfromMoscow, it's easier to read the intent with named functions

Comment: @VladfromMoscow agreed in most cases :) ! my personal preference is lambdas for anything ad-hoc less than 1 or 2 lines; named functions for everything else; from my perspective having to remember X unary predicates is a bit more hassle than having to remember one common mechanism; but lambdas can become complex to read and understand when they get large;

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no technical reason why your second approach should be disallowed. Prior to deprecation, `std::bind2nd` helper function would come very close to your desired approach:

```
std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::bind2nd(std::less_equal<int>(), 42));
```

Of course you can always make your own helper - it is very short:

```
template <typename T> auto cmp_less_equal(const T& x) {
  return std::bind(std::less_equal<T>(), std::placeholders::_1, x);
}
```

Now you can write

```
std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), cmp_less_equal(42));
```

using your own wrapper ([demo](http://ideone.com/CKCau7)).

Answer (score 3):

How about you just give a lambda a name?

```
const auto cmp_less_eq = [](auto x){ return x <= 42; };
const auto result = find_if(begin(v), end(v), cmp_less_eq);
```

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but the whole idea of the standard library is to provide common functionality even if it is really easy to implement. There are many examples of one liners in the standard library just because they happen to be used very often

Comment: I'm not trying to argue what should/should not be in the standard. I'm just attempting to provide a way to solve your problem :-)

Comment: My question was more about the reasons behind omitting this functionality in the standard library than to solve the problem and yes, I think this is a more elegant solution than the bind one I used as a sample. +1:)